# Copy and Paste from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am collating data of different worksheet.

The problem is when copying data into the destination file, all the data are placed into one column.

The code below is a snippet of the part where the problem occurs.

```
Workbooks.Open (Folderpath & Filename)
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Lastrow, Lastcolumn)).Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
erow = ThisIsAWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ThisIsAWS.Paste Destination:=ThisIsAWS.Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, Lastcolumn))
Filename = Dir
```

This is how a file would look initially.
[image: Source]

After going through the macro, it ends up like this.
[image: ![Destination]

When I do it manually where I copy (ctrl + c) and paste (ctrl + v) using the same data, it comes out fine.

For the source file, the data might have been placed in a table, so would this play a role to why it ends up in one column in the destination file?

EDIT: Source picture. I might have found the problem but still in need of a solution. The column B and C are merged together in this picture. Could this be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro works fine for me. However, you could try to set the ranges equal using `.value` rather than `.copy`:

```
Dim to_rng as Range
Dim rng_loop as Range

Workbooks.Open (Folderpath & Filename)
    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    erow = ThisIsAWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Set to_rng = ThisIsAWS.Range(ThisIsAWS.Cells(erow, 1), ThisIsAWS.Cells(erow + Lastrow - 2, Lastcolumn))
    to_rng.value = ActiveSheet.range(ActiveSheet.cells(2,1), ActiveSheet.cells(Lastrow, Lastcolumn)).value

    For loop1 = Lastcolumn To 1 Step -1
        Set rng_loop = ThisIsAWS.Range(ThisIsAWS.Cells(erow, loop1), ThisIsAWS.Cells((erow + Lastrow - 2), loop1))
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_loop) = 0 Then
            rng_loop.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    Next loop1

    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Filename = Dir
```

The loop moves backwards (step -1) through each column in the added range and if all cells in the range column are empty (CountA = 0), then it deletes the column by shifting the entire row to the left.

Original data:

[image]

Data added to other file:

[image]

Comment: I made an edit. Could you try it again with the merged column as shown in my first picture. It will help to reproduce my problem.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the merged cells?

Comment: No need of keeping the cells merged.

Comment: How exactly would you like the output to look like? Exactly like in the first picture, just without merged cells?

Comment: Yes exactly. So, column B and C would just be column B. Then the rest just follows. Total of 4 columns which would range from A to D.

Comment: You could use a loop to remove the extra cells.

Comment: I tried your solution. There is nothing copied over to the other worksheet.

Comment: I am not sure about what exactly your data looks like. I have recreated the problem based on the image above and it seems to work (see my images).

Comment: Oh. It works. Its very slow though if the files are huge. Is it because of the for loop that causes it to take up time? The macro I made is used to collate data from multiple worksheet into one. So, it would be doing it for 30+ files of about 1000 rows each and 17 columns.

Comment: Updated the loop to no longer go through each cell. Should be faster now.

Comment: Oh wow. It is much faster than before and does exactly what I want it do. Could you explain the for loop part a little bit. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help. Added a short loop explanation to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Closed Too Early

```
  With Workbooks.Open(Folderpath & Filename).ActiveSheet
    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Lastcolumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    erow = ThisIsAWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Lastrow, Lastcolumn)).Copy _
        Destination:=ThisIsAWS.Cells(erow, 1)
    .Parent.Close False
  End With
  Filename = Dir
```

Comment: I am getting an error message from this line `.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Lastrow, Lastcolumn)).Copy Destination:=ThisIsAWS.Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, Lastcolumn))`. The error is Run-time Error '1004' Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Comment: DSM: Try '.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Lastrow, Lastcolumn)).Copy Destination:=ThisIsAWS.Cells(erow, 1)'.

Comment: your solution works but it leaves behind the merged cells. How to get rid of them? Would doing it like in VBA Pete's solution the way?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I found a way to use your solution as well by adding a few lines of code to get rid of the merged columns.